# Capturing Only Date & Month for a Date in Salesforce

Tags: picklist, datetime, date, dependent-picklist

We have a requirement to capture only "Date" & "Month" for a field (for e.g. Birth Date).

We don't want to capture birth year. 
I think the best way to capture this in Salesforce would be by using dependent picklist by using "Month" as controlling field "Date" as dependent field.

Any thought on other idea to capture only "Date" and "Month" in Salesforce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one of the possible options, although you can't control leap years and having February changing the dependent values every 4 years :). What else you can do is - create a text field (5 characters) and create some validation rules to ensure the entered dates are valid. Also it will help keeping your data consistent across the org.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I would like to go with Picklist option. As we are not capturing year, even if user selects Feb 29, that should be fine. In future, if we need some validation, we can validate based on the "Month" + "Day" picklist combination.

Comment: True that, if you're not capturing year you won't know. Neither of the solutions is wrong, it's up to you which path you take.